# Error: database or disk is full (code 13 SQLITE_FULL) when filling aws amplify datastore table with content

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

as soon as i fill my aws amplify datastore tables with over 10000 lines of content, i get the error in my react native expo app as soon as the datastore is read or written to

```
WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):
Array [
  [Error: database or disk is full (code 13 SQLITE_FULL)],
]
```

If I delete or clear the tables, the error does not occur. This error doesnt occur on iOS as well.

This is the size of my 3 tables:[image: Table Size]

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.